# File access outside application directory

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

I want to know is it possible to access files outside the application directory? e.g. /home/phablet, /media, etc.

Okay, so precisely I want to use QDir and QFile to read the folders and the files under /home/phablet, but then I found that I got permission denied when trying to run on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Content Hub](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/content-hub-guide/) to access them, it will allow the user to select which files to give your app access to.

Comment: Is it possible to use content hub from C++?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some information so we know what you are specifically after.

The direct answer to your question is "yes", but that's not likely to be helpful to you.

Comment: updated original question